# Music app - half my songs are really quiet, within an album

Tags: macbook-pro, sound-volume, music.app, mp3

I've just started using a Mcbook Air(Big Sur, 11.5.1, M1 chipset) after being a Linux/Windows user for years.  I brought over my MP3 collection from my old Thinkpad and imported into the Music app.

For most albums, the tracks alternate between being normal volume and **really quiet**.  Like 'I can barely hear it' quiet.  I've tried switching on the Sound Check option in the Preferences, but it doesn't make any difference - it doesn't seem to do anything in fact.

If it was that one album was louder than another, I could maybe understand it, but for it to alternate within an album, I just don't understand.  It's not an exact quiet-loud-quiet-loud-quiet-loud alternation btw - sometimes it might go quiet-quiet-loud-quiet-loud-loud for example.  But, it's roughly a 50/50 split.

It also doesn't happen with every album - just most albums.

When i listened to them on the old laptop, they were all the same volume (with maybe a slight difference on an album-by-album basis but nothing like this).

I opened a "quiet" one and a loud one in Audacity and the peak db is the same in both, and if I listen to them out of Audacity they sound the same volume.  So the issue is definitely with the playback in the Music app rather than the files themselves, unless there is some metadata Music is reading and adjusting the playback volume accordingly.  If there was, though, i don't know why it would go up and down so much within an album.

Any ideas anyone?

EDIT - I downloaded Elmedia player and they all play fine in that - same volume.  I would still prefer to fix them in Music though as it's a nicer interface.

Comment: there's an app called [iVolume](https://www.mani.de/en/ivolume/) that will adjust Sound Check levels, though I'm not sure it is the fix to your issue, as it manifests with Sound Check on or off. Maybe your files have a manual adjustment already set, which Audacity would ignore. Have a look at a couple of affected files, Get Info on a few of the tracks in Music & see if they've been set

Comment: Does the happen regardless of output device (e.g., internal speakers, analog wired headset, Bluetooth wireless headset)?

Comment: @pion I've only tried with wired headphones.

Comment: @Tetsujin i downloaded Elmedia Player and they're all fine in that, so it does seem to something about the Music app.  I will look at the files though.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Can you try with other outputs?

Comment: @pion i just unplugged the headphones so it's using the macbook speaker and it has the same problem.

Comment: @Tetsujin - you were right about the Volume Adjust option:  the quiet tracks have it set to -90% and the loud ones have it set to +100%!  This is only true of MP3 tracks that I have owned for a long time - with an album I downloaded recently, Volume Adjust is set to 0% on all tracks.  So, i guess i need to set it to 0% for everything.  I wonder if I can do that en mass in the terminal?  (i'm a software dev so am fairly handy with that sort of thing).  BTW I think you have hit the nail on the head here - if you want to write an answer about Volume Adjust i will mark it correct.

Comment: @Tetsujin i just discovered that (in the Music app) you can select multiple tracks and then click Get Info to edit the settings for them all at once, and then set Volume Adjust back to 0% there.  That has fixed my albums.  Hooray!

Comment: @MaxWilliams please write that up as an answer. You can also accept it yourself

Comment: @mmmmmm i will if Tetsujin doesn't want to.

Comment: I don’t need the points. Go for it;)

Answer (score 4):

This turned out to be due to a setting on the individual MP3s which tells some players to turn them up or down.  I don't know what the technical metadata field in the file is called but within the Music app it's called "volume adjust" and can be seen by right clicking on a track, choosing Get Info and then going to the Options tab.

In the problem albums, every track was set to either -90% or +100% in this 'volume adjust' setting.  Obviously this setting is ignored in Audacity and Elmedia, the other player app I tried.

Fortunately it's possible to select multiple tracks (eg all tracks by a given artist or even all of your library I suppose), right click and Get Info, then go to the Options tab and set that 'volume adjust' to 0%.

As to how they got like that, I don't know.  I have a vague memory of mucking about with a command line utility in linux for adjusting mp3 volumes, 10 or 15 years ago, and I suspect it was that which set these ridiculous volume adjust settings, which all the players I've been using have ignored, until now.