# Music app shows a -x dB for some songs

Tags: sound-volume, music.app

Similar to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/430972/music-app-half-my-songs-are-really-quiet-within-an-album) I have a few music files inside music.app that plays very quietly.

After opening "Get Info" of the songs, the last tab shows a "volume" with - 3db (or less or more)

[image]

But the "volume adjust" of the same song is set to 0% in the option tab

[image]

How can I remove the -3 dB of the songs, and all the songs that may have this issue in Music ? (I have more than 40k songs so checking them one by one is going to take forever...)

Perhaps another app can help me with that ?

Comment: Same as the linked question; list by songs, select all, set to zero. [Don't touch anything else & it will change only the one parameter].

Comment: But it's already set to zero as the 2nd picture shows

Comment: Ah, OK, sorry. That's the Sound Check volume not the manual. iTunes sets that itself the first time you load a new file. You can't change it or even discard it once it's set, other than by using [iVolume](https://www.mani.de/en/ivolume/). This is the only app I know of that can adjust Sound Check. There might be others but I haven't found them. If that doesn't work, then you'd have to look for something that will adjust ReplayGain instead. Sound Check has always been a bit hit & miss.

Comment: Thanks, I checked iVolume as you spoke about it on the linked question. Unfortunatly it seems that I have to go song by song so it's will take too much time (as I don't know wich songs have the gain set wrong...) I was wondering if iTunes may do that. If I find another app to help I will gladly post it here !

Comment: Whatever app you use, it will have to test what it considers 'correct' against what has already been set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a "Sound Check"  checkbox on the Playback tab inside Music's Preferences that seems to adjust all files inside Music

[image]

It seems to work so far (it taked a long time to adjust all my songs but managed it to the end at least)